# LocationServices не возвращает location

Tags: android, геолокация, android-location

Доброго времени суток!
Наткнулся на следующую проблему с `LocationServices`, не  могу получить текущее местоположение. Сам метод `findLocation()`. 
Проблема в том, что `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` не вызывает `onLocationChanged`, а `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mClient);` возвращает `null`.

А и еще проблема решается перезапуском эмулятора... 
И почему-то на моем nexus 5 android 6.0.1 вылетает с ошибкой...
Буду благодарен любой подсказке.

Весь код ниже.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;



public class LocationFragment extends Fragment{ 

//Widget
private Location mLocation;
private TextView mCityResultTextView;
private TextView mLongitudeTextView;
private TextView mLatitudeTextView;

//List Widget&Adapter
private RecyclerView mLocationRecyclerView;
private LocationAdapter mAdapter;

//DataStorage
private List<CityLocation> mCityLocations;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

//Location
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private GoogleApiClient mClient;

private ProgressDialog mDialog;

public static LocationFragment newInstance() {
    return new LocationFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    findLocation();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                }
            })
            .build();


    mDatabase = new LocationBaseHelper(getContext())
            .getWritableDatabase();

    mCityLocations = getCityLocations();
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
    mCityResultTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.city_result_textView);
    mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.longitude_result_textView);
    mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.latitude_result_textView);

    mLocationRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.location_recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mLocationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    Button addLocationButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.add_location);
    addLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //findCityLocation();
            findLocation();
        }
    });

    updateUI();
    return v;
}

private void updateUI(){
    mCityLocations = getCityLocations();
    if (mCityLocations.size() > 0) {
        CityLocation city =  mCityLocations.get(mCityLocations.size() - 1);
        mLatitudeTextView.setText(city.getLatLocation());
        mLongitudeTextView.setText(city.getLongLocation());
        mCityResultTextView.setText(city.getCity());
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new LocationAdapter(mCityLocations);
            mLocationRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.setCityLocation(mCityLocations);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mLocationRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        }

    }
}

private String getAddressFromLocation(){
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude(), 1);

        if (addresses != null) {
            if (!addresses.get(0).getLocality().equals("")) {
                return addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            } else {
                return "Нет адресов!";
            }
        }
        else {
            return "Нет адресов!";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Не могу получить адрес!";
    }
}



private boolean checkLocation() {
    if(!isLocationEnabled())
        showAlert();
    return isLocationEnabled();
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    boolean temp1 = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean temp2 = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    return (temp1||temp2);

}

private void showAlert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
            .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                    "use this app")
            .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}

public void findLocation(){
    if(!checkLocation())
        return;

    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setNumUpdates(1);
    request.setInterval(0);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .requestLocationUpdates(mClient, request, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got a fix: " + location);
                    mLocation = location;
                    CityLocation cityLocation = new CityLocation();
                    if (mLocation != null) {
                        //получаем адрес
                        cityLocation.setCity(getAddressFromLocation());

                        //подготавливаем данные для БД
                        cityLocation.setLocation(mLocation);
                        mCityLocations.add(cityLocation);
                        addLocations(cityLocation);

                        //Обновляем представление
                        updateUI();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        cityLocation.setCity( "Location not Detected");
                    }
                }
            });
//реализация вторая
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mClient);
    CityLocation cityLocation = new CityLocation();
    if (mLocation != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), mLocation.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //получаем адрес
        cityLocation.setCity(getAddressFromLocation());

        //подготавливаем данные для БД
        cityLocation.setLocation(mLocation);
        mCityLocations.add(cityLocation);
        addLocations(cityLocation);

        //Обновляем представление
        updateUI();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cityLocation.setCity( "Location not Detected");
    }

}


//Database
private static ContentValues getContentValues(CityLocation cityLocation) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LocationTable.Cols.TITLE, cityLocation.getCity());
    values.put(LocationTable.Cols.LATITUDE, cityLocation.getLatLocation());
    values.put(LocationTable.Cols.LONGITUDE, cityLocation.getLongLocation());
    return values;
}

public void addLocations(CityLocation cityLocation) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(cityLocation);
    mDatabase.insert(LocationTable.NAME, null, values);
}

private CityLocationCursorWrapper queryCityLocations(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
            LocationTable.NAME,
            null, // Columns - null выбирает все столбцы
            whereClause,
            whereArgs,
            null, // groupBy
            null, // having
            null // orderBy
    );
    return new CityLocationCursorWrapper(cursor);
}

public List<CityLocation> getCityLocations() {
    List<CityLocation> cityLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    try (CityLocationCursorWrapper cursor = queryCityLocations(null, null)) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cityLocations.add(cursor.getCityLocation());
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return cityLocations;
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mClient.disconnect();
}
}
```

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fgurbanov.skynet.in_search_hire_test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.fgurbanov.skynet.in_search_hire_test">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
            />-
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Вылетает на вашем устройстве, потому что вы не дали разрешения. В андроиде 6 есть такое понятие как Runtime Permission. https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, ошибка оказалась в сохранении данных в SQLite. Была проблема проблема с преобразованием от Location.toString  и обратно из-за языка системы, т.к. в русской версии в double ставится запятая, а не точка. А эмулятор не корректно отрабатывал сохранение в БД и тем самым не выдавал результаты получения местоположения. Вот такой очень странный баг. 
По поводу разрешений, т.к. был target sdk 22 проблем с ними быть не должно. А по поводу написания сервиса для получения место положения, это не логично в рамках такой маленькой задачи, как получения местоположения по нажатию кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Привет ,Твой код большой и корявый)Не могу читать так как щас занет сервлетом .Но вот тебе рабочий код определения местоположения 
:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="testing.gps_service.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Service"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop Service"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="top|right"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Coordinates: "
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Это разметка а в это код (мозг)):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_start, btn_stop;
    private TextView textView;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(broadcastReceiver == null){
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    textView.append("\n" +intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));

                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(broadcastReceiver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn_stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if(!runtime_permissions())
            enable_buttons();

    }

    private void enable_buttons() {

        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
                startService(i);
            }
        });

        btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
                stopService(i);

            }
        });

    }

    private boolean runtime_permissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == 100){
            if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                enable_buttons();
            }else {
                runtime_permissions();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {

    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

            listener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                    i.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());
                    sendBroadcast(i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            };

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(locationManager != null){
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```